# Analytical Solution of 2nd-order linear ODE $ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = x $, boundary condition $ y(0) = 0,\ y(0.1) = 0.001 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Analytical Solution of 2nd-order linear ODE: $ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = x $,
Boundary Condition: $ y(0) = 0,\ y(0.1) = 0.001 $

$ \int \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} dx = \int x dx = \frac{x^2}{2} + C_1 $
$ \int \frac{d y}{dx} dx = \int (\frac{x^2}{2} + C_1) dx $
$ y(x) = \frac{x^3}{6} + C_1 x + C_2 $
$ y(0) = 0 $ gives $\ C_2 = 0 $
$ y(0.1) = 0.001 $ gives $\ C_1 = \frac{5}{600} $
$ y(x) = \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{5}{600} x $

Does the analytical solution look correct? Thank you.

Comment: I just edited for a quick correction on the ODE: $ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = x $, thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to ask if it looks correct, just check it. Verify that $y''(x)=x$ and that the boundary conditions are satsified.

Comment: I checked the analytical soln. though. Just I got difference from numerical soln., so I asked here.